# How do you auto increment a varchar value in db2?

Tags: sql, db2

I have tried this but I'm getting an error:

> SQLCODE = -104, ERROR:  ILLEGAL SYMBOL "'T'". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT
>   BE LEGAL ARE: LOCATOR SECURITY

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT_REGISTER
(              
SNO INT NOT NULL ,                          
STUDENT_ID AS 'T'+CAST( SNO AS VARCHAR(10)) 
PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY,                      
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20),                     
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(20),                      
DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE,                         
ADDRESS VARCHAR(100),                       
MOBILE_NO BIGINT                            
)
```

Comment: if i run your code i.e.,concat statementit returned SQLCODE = -199, ERROR:  ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD CONCAT.  TOKEN LOCATOR
SECURITY WAS EXPECTED

Comment: ifi run by using 'as' sqlcode=-104 returned

Comment: you can try `STUDENT_ID VARCHAR(10) WITH DEFAULT 'T'+SNO`. If it is not taking `+` for concatenation, you can try using `||`

Comment: Why are you prefacing the number with a `T`?  I'm worried you're going to be using this as a multi-part key (which is frowned on).  Ideally, you should probably have a regular integer (autogen) column for the primary key, and then have an additional unique key column for any "issued" id; this shouldn't reflect the actual database-internal (primary) key.  Among other things, it would make it much easier to change the externally visible ids, if you ended up with sufficient students...

Answer (score 1):

You can write a trigger instead,

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo BEFORE INSERT ON STUDENT_REGISTER FOR EACH ROW
  IF NEW.STUDENT_ID IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.STUDENT_ID := 't' + NEW.SNO;
  END IF;;
```

You can try this out and let me know , i haven't tried it out myself but i am quite sure that it should work so please try it and let me know if it worked or not